# Ubuntu Server does not detect RAID HDD

Tags: filesystem, format

I have formatted in a [low level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_formatting#Low-level_formatting_.28LLF.29_of_hard_disks) the hard disks of my computer. When I try to install Ubuntu Server I get this error message:

```
[!!] Partition disks
  No root file system
No root file system is defined.
Please correct this from the partitioning menu.
```

I do not reach the step that shows: Partitionning method in order to choose the manual or guided installation in order to mount manually the root filesystem.

When I deactivate the RAID option, I see the 2 HDDs I have. But When I activate the RAID option, I can not see the HDD at all.

No doubt that I correctly configured the RAID array, however.

Is not Ubuntu able to define a filesystem on HDDs that have not (the ones that are formatted in a low level) ? How can I fix this trouble ?

Comment: can you explain: "formatted in a low level" please?

Comment: Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_formatting#Low-level_formatting_.28LLF.29_of_hard_disks

Comment: LOL, we know what a low level format is, we are asking how did you do this exactly.

Comment: @begueradj It seems like you try to get FakeRAID or some proprietary RAID controller to work with Ubuntu. This is [not recommended](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Linux_Raid#Hardware_RAID). Use `mdadm`, `btrfs` or *ZFS on Linux* instead. Also what the RAID controller does with the hard drives is different (higher level) to what is described in the article. It's safe to assume that you didn't even read this section of the article to the end, right? Anyway, go read up on `mdadm` and ZFS. This will get you started the right way.

Comment: @LiveWireBT I resolved the problem a moment ago, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a "custom" partitioning. If you do that you will need to tell it which partition will contain the root filesystem. Look at the column "Mount Point" (if memory servers me well...)

Without a root filesystem the installer is unable to continue.

Comment: I think by your answer we are close to the solution, however I am trying to install Ubuntu Server (no interface). How can I mount the root filesystem ?

Comment: Use the installer to (1) create your partition(s), (2) tell it which partition is mounted where and (3) what filesystem should be used on each partition. IIRC the installer will ask you to write the changes after step (1).  Don't forget to create a swap partition too.

Comment: How can I access the terminal commands during the installation to perform the tasks you listed above ? When I press ESC just after choosing the language, I run for example fdisk -l and it says the command is not found.

Comment: I think you need to look at the [official guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/amd64/ch06s03.html#di-partition)

Comment: I understand which step you mean then. But that is my problem: I do not reach that step that allows me to mount what I want manually, guided and so on. In fact, my system does not detect the RAID hard disks when I press YES for the message : "Activate Serial ATA RAID devices ?' I do not reach the step that shows: Partitionning method in order to choose the manual or guided installation.

Comment: Well, noting useful can happen if the hard disks aren't detected. Perhaps answer No to the raid quiestion and configure software raid? Sorry, can't help you any further.

Comment: I resolved the problem a short moment ago, thank you very much